# XML LOAD DATA INFILE childnode value overrides parent nodes value

Tags: mysql, xml, database, load-data-infile

I want to get the value of the parent child node in XML but the value of the childnode is overriding it because they're of the same name

How do I make it pick the parent node value without the childnode value overriding it?

I'm using LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'person.xml'
INTO TABLE document
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<document>';
```

This is the sample XML data

```
<document>
      <name>John</name>
      <age>19</age>
      <street>
                <name>Johnson Street</name>
      </street>
</document>
```

Instead of the name tag under document tag to print John it's printing Johnson Street

Comment: rename the second to fullname, and don't use duplicate names for different hierarchy  sections

Comment: Is there anyway to rename it programmatically without affecting the others? The file is a large file of almost 40Mb I think.

Comment: see if the prigram that generates the xml can be changed, else if you god thousands if xml files you have to write a simple program

Answer (score 1):

It should be doable using xpath:

```
SET @xml = '<document>
      <name>John</name>
      <age>19</age>
      <street>
                <name>Johnson Street</name>
      </street>
</document>
';
SET @i =1;
SELECT @i, ExtractValue(@xml, './/street/name');
```

[You can try it here.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jdNrBMRm8AMxyuRhz2b2bt/0)

Comment: Bad Design is bad design

Comment: @nbk Indeed it is!